# Python don't modify values while iterating over a list with zip(), but does it while with enumerate()

Tags: python, list, for-loop, variables

Why Python works differently when iterating using index numbers? For example with the zip function (that don't has indexes when used in the for loop) a value isn't stored in a variable. While with the enumerate() function (that allow me to have an "index" in the foor loop)  it happens normally.

A solution that don't use index has different values for my "width" variable when I'm trying to print it inside and outside the loop, here the zip() function was used to work with the two lists at the same time without needing to deal with their indexes:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
            ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printTable(myListOfLists):
    colWidths = [0] * len(myListOfLists)
    for lists, width in zip(myListOfLists, colWidths):
        for item in lists:
            if width < len(item):
                width = len(item)
        print(width) #This prints my 'width' rightly
    print(colWidths) #This prints my 'width' wrongly

printTable(tableData)
```

The above code produces the following **not desired** output:

```
8
5
5
[0, 0, 0]
```

But if I use enumerate() (generating indexes to work with the two lists at the same time) the values modified inside my for loop will be properly saved in the width variable, see the code example:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
            ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printTable(myListOfLists):
    colWidths = [0] * len(myListOfLists)
    for index, lists in enumerate(myListOfLists):
        for item in lists:
            if colWidths[index] < len(item):
                colWidths[index] = len(item)
        print(colWidths[index]) #This prints my 'width' rightly
    print(colWidths) #This ALSO prints my 'width' rightly

printTable(tableData)
```

This second output is:

```
8
5
5
[8, 5, 5]
```

Then, please, how can I work with the zip() and have my "external" variable modified? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: By `width = len(item)` you're reassigning variable (changing it's value from list to another one) `width` with `len(item)` value, you not working with list but with variable itself.

In second scenario `colWidths` is also list but you're affecting it by changing item under certain index.

Comment: Please what's the right way to do it then? @Damian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by this way you wont change the value of the list you need the index to change the real value.

example:

```
for e in [1, 2, 3]:
    e = 10  # this way is wrong 

data = [1, 2, 3]
for index, e in enumerate(data):
    e[index] = 50 # always it is needed an index
```

a good way to solve your problem:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]


data = [len(max(e, key=len)) for e in tableData]

print(data)
```

or

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
            ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
            ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

def printTable(myListOfLists):
    colWidths = [0] * len(myListOfLists)
    for index, row in enumerate(myListOfLists):
        colWidths[index] = len(max(row, key=len))
    print(colWidths)

printTable(tableData)
```

on another hand you could try out.

```
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(alist, blist)):
    print i, a, b
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you fully answered it. Specially for being so objective and for
"for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(alist, blist)):
    print i, a, b"

Answer (score 2):

I believe, what you want to achieve is to get length of longest item in given sub-list from `tableData`. To do that you can get longest string from sub-list and then measure its length like this:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]


def printTable(myListOfLists):
    colWidths = []
    for sub_list in myListOfLists:
        longest_item = max(sub_list, key=len)
        colWidths.append(len(longest_item))
    print(colWidths)


printTable(tableData)
```

edit with explanation:

By using `for lists, width in zip(myListOfLists, colWidths):`

on each cycle you're getting 
1) single list with strings from tableData as `lists`.
2) integer, exactly 0 from colWidths as `width`

then, on iteration over each text like 'apples', 'oranges' etc.

what you're doing in here:
`width = len(item)` is like saying "now width isn't 0 anymore, it's `len(item)`, by this you're not affecting list `colWidths` because you're not working with it, you're manipulating this `0` value, it's not related to place in `colWidths` list, it's just 0 which is replaced by `len(item)` under "width" name.

Comment: I tried to leave your code as much as possible in the original form, that's why there are different naming conventions (one with underscores and one as CamelCase)

Comment: Damian, thanks but I'm trying to:
1) understand why my code doesn't works as expected.
2) understand how can it work using the zip, the for and the if. Even if it's not the best solution. 

Thanks for you solution, but it's still don't answer my question.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. I will edit message with explanation.

Comment: It's for learning purposes, do you comprehend? I need to understand why is this behaving in this way. Then I'll not repeat the same mistake. Sorry, but if you could add these "details" to your answer.

Comment: No problem! That's even more motivating for me to explain!


My answer can be little chaotic but I hope you will get the point.

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate` is a Pythonic way of generating indices (similar to, but more idiomatic, `for i in range(len(...):`

```
colWidths = [0] * len(myListOfLists)
for index, lists in enumerate(myListOfLists):
    for item in lists:
        if colWidths[index] < len(item):
            colWidths[index] = len(item)
```

Here `lists` and `item` come from `myListOfLists`, but you explicitly modifying `colWidths` list.

In the first case, you are modifying an iteration variable, but not the source list:

```
colWidths = [0] * len(myListOfLists)
for lists, width in zip(myListOfLists, colWidths):
    for item in lists:
        if width < len(item):
            width = len(item)
```

`width` is an iteration variable.  But the `width = len(item)` line assigns a new value to the variable (name), breaking its link with the source array.  On the next iteration, `width` is again set by the iterator.  The source list, `colWidths` does not change.

This pattern is true for simple cases:

```
alist = [1,2,3,4]
for i in alist:
   i = 5     # does nothing to alist

for i in range(4):
    alist[i] = 5    # changes an element of alist
```

Changes to the iteration variable are tricky.  You have to understand when it represents something 'mutable', and not.  And understand the difference between assignment to a variable, and modifying an object (like a list).